# Converting the code from FOR loop to WHILE loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

for i in range (1, num+1):
    if (i%2==0):
        i = i // 2
        print(3**(i-1))
    else:
        i = i // 2 + 1
        print(2**(i-1))
```

***TO***

```
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

i=1
j=1
while j<=num and i<=num:
    if (i%2==0):
        i = i // 2
        print(3**(i-1))
    else:
        i = i // 2 + 1
        print(2**(i-1))
j+1
```

**Facing problem in while loop conversion.**
Searched this problem everywhere on the internet but unable to solve it.

Comment: what is the point of `j`?

Comment: `j` is not being incremented within the `while` loop, so it will never satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I think `i` value get changed when it enters inside the loop. So used `j`. Not able to find a way of incrementing the value of `i`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You need to increment `j` within the loop and you will need to use `j += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will accomplish what you want:

```
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

i = 1
while i <= num:
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        print(3 ** ((i // 2) - 1))
    else:
        print(2 ** (i // 2))
    i += 1
```

`i` will increment by 1 after each loop. Which mimics `for i in range(1, num + 1)`. `i` is not modified within the loop, it is only used in the printed calculation.

Note: in your `for` loop, your modifications to `i` do not affect the `i` variable for the loop but I would suggest that you try to avoid using the same variable name within the loop.